# How to update position of plt.axvspan object on a Python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, interactive

So I have a selector slider beneath a graph to grab a certain slice of data.  I want to use an axvspan object to overlay on top of the graph to act as a selector, showing what data is being grabbed for the slice.  I can get the axvspan object to display initially, but apparently it has no set_data() function that I can use to move it.  How can I move it?  Or are there any alternatives?